# Как присвоить 2 модульных класса одновременно? (React)

Tags: css, reactjs, модульность

Имеется блок, который должен по клику менять свой внешний вид.
Хочу при клике менять значение стейта и в зависимости от значения присваивать доп. класс.

```
<div className={`${style.card}  ${count === 1 ? style.additional : ''}`}></div>
```

Первый класс `card` всегда присвоен и работает, а `additional` должен присваиваться при клике. Но при клике, вместо класса, в консоли, я вижу `undefiend`.
Если я подобным образом вывожу обычные текстовые классы - всё работает как надо. Но мне нужна модульность.
Как решить данную проблему?

Comment: Как я понял, корень проблемы лежит в том, что классы создаются отдельной библиотекой. т.к. изначально класс additional  я не использую при формировании страницы, библиотека его не создаёт и соответственно я получаю undefiend если уже потом использую. Если создать еще один div где применить этот класс, то приведённый выше код работает

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Решил через костыль: создал дополнительный div которому присвоил нужный мне класс, а через style указал visibility: hidden. Работает.

Может есть более элегантное решение?

Answer (score 0):

className={style.imgWillChoose + ' ' + style.imgIsChoosing}

Comment: добро пожаловать на Stack Overflow на русском! пожалуйста, оставляйте чуть более развёрнутые ответы. [постарайтесь рассказать обо всех нюансах, которые могут возникнуть при решении проблемы по вашему сценарию. изложите свои предложения. возможен и краткий ответ, но чем подробнее и понятнее он будет изложен, тем лучше](https://ru.stackoverflow.com/help/how-to-answer). дополнить ответ можно, нажав [edit]